# How can I transfer tab data from the Chrome App to another phone - including back and forward data?

Tags: backup, chrome-for-android, data-transfer, browser-tabs

So my nexus 6p is getting on in years, and I'd like to back up my chrome tabs onto another phone. I'm aware there's a sync function, but that:

1. Does not cover the back and forward data from each tab, and
2. Does not seem to go past a few dozen tabs - I have around 1000+ tabs
   open.

Is there anything I can do to move or transfer the data, or should I just get to searching through each tab and copy-pasting them? Also, the phone isn't currently rooted from what I recall - I'm willing to try it but I've been told that may be counterproductive and likely wipe the data. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would assume the the developers of web browser never imagined that people could use their app this way therefore all the available sync options don't match your requirements. Typically tabs are nothing persistent, they are of temporary nature. BTW: Is a web browser really useful with 1000 tabs open? How do you navigate between them?